How to unit test a form using the useActionState hook?
I want to test a form with the useActionState hook. It does use simply async function, not a server action. I would like to assert the state to be incremented, but the test fails even before I can make such assertion.
import React from "react";
import { useActionState } from "react";
import { describe, test, expect } from "vitest";
import { act, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { userEvent } from "@testing-library/user-event";

describe("useActionState", () => {
  test("it works", async () => {
    async function increment(previousState: number, formData: any) {
      return previousState + 1;
    }

    function StatefulForm({}) {
      const [state, formAction] = useActionState(increment, 0);
      return (
        <>
          <p data-testid="state">{state}</p>
          <form action={formAction}>
            <button type="submit" data-testid="submit">
              Increment
            </button>
          </form>
        </>
      );
    }

    const { debug } = render(<StatefulForm />);

    expect(screen.getByTestId("state")).toBeInTheDocument();

    debug();

    const submit = screen.getByTestId("submit");
    await act(() => userEvent.click(submit));
    // throws error:
    // Error: A React form was unexpectedly submitted. If you called form.submit() manually,   consider using form.requestSubmit() instead. If you're trying to use event.stopPropagation()      in a submit event handler, consider also calling event.preventDefault().

  });
});


As it turns out the "action" prop creates an implicit Action Context (which throws the error).
We can avoid this by creating explicit Action Context, by using the useTransition hook:
    import { type FormEvent, useTransition } from "react";
    
    function StatefulForm({}) {
      const [state, formAction] = useActionState(increment, 0);
      const [, startTransition] = useTransition();
      return (
        <>
          <p data-testid="state">{state}</p>
          <form
            onSubmit={(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
              // by using custom event handler, we can prevent the reset of form
              event.preventDefault();
              const form = event.currentTarget;
    
              // the formAction must be called in an ActionContext - transition
              startTransition(() => {
                formAction(new FormData(form));
              });
            }}
          >
            <button type="submit" data-testid="submit">
              Increment
            </button>
          </form>
        </>
      );
    }

